# What is the order priority of a Dagger of Paranoia and a Potion of Ineptitude in online werewolv.es?

Tags: werewolv.es

If a player activates a Dagger of Paranoia (to kill a random night visitor), and another player visits them to cast a Potion of Ineptitude on them to disable active item use that night, which takes precedence?  Does the Dagger-holder kill the person visiting with the Potion, or does the person administering the Potion to inactivate the Dagger use get there first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Potion is marked as a **blocking** item, which are executed before non-blocking items.

So you could use a Potion of Ineptitude on a player using a dagger and the dagger should not activate, so you would be safe from harm.